# cant access files that have includes with relative URls

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've taken over a site that caters for client access. They all access there own folder, and in the folder the files have an include with a relative path as below.

/core - contains all the actual files

/client/file.php -

```
<? include "../core/file.php"; ?>
```

but with the growing number of clients I want to go a level deeper and separate them better...

/uk/client/file.php -

```
<? include "../../core/file.php"; ?>
```

This is fine but when the files are included, they too have there own relative includes and this is where it breaks.

There are so many files I can't easily go through them to change all the include paths so I would like to maybe do a rewrite to fake the path?

I've tried this...

```
RewriteRule ^uk/$ /
```

But that doesn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It would generally be recommendable with a project of this scale to have variables containing the most commonly used paths in your project (like the `core` folder). This way, if you need to change your paths, you can do it in a single location.

Comment: I will get round to doing this as I've just taken over the site but I need a quick fix for now

Answer (score 0):

This sound like a work for `__DIR__`, you can check [documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

> The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned. This is equivalent to dirname(**FILE**). This directory name does not have a trailing slash unless it is the root directory. (Added in PHP 5.3.0.)

Otherwise you can still switch all your relative paths to absolute path and avoid any problem if some file are included in others.

As side note i would reccomend to not use php short tag `<?...?>`, I'd rather use long tags `<?php....?>`

Comment: Hi... this will add the path to where I the include is though? so /server_path/uk/client/core/file.php

Comment: @jhodgson4 yeah, you can give it a try, anyway for a quick fix I would rather use `absolute path` in any require/include

Comment: I can do that but the include paths within the included file will still be wrong :-(. There must be a way to do this with htaccess